# Having issue in initialising Reactjs showing ENOENT error how to debug this

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vOwR.png)When I'm initialising react in command prompt
npx create-react-app my-app
It's showing this ENOENT error.

I guess I didn't install node js correctly I have checked Chocolatey during installation. Do I have to delete node js & install it again....???

Comment: Kindly don't post the code or error as image. [Refer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) this for better understanding.

Comment: Do check whether node have been installed using `node --version`, if and then check `npm --version`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved it completely but I think this Github page can be helpful - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you've probably hit [this bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/52018) in Node `v21.7.0`; if you can downgrade to `v21.6.2` for now that will most likely work.